# asp.net core with react redirection issues bff pattern

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, auth0, duende

I'm trying to understand how the routing should work from the frontend to the backend.
I'm using the duende.bff package in asp.net core 7 and have this setup according to the documentation and this tutorial: https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/lets-make-our-spa-more-secure-by-setting-up-a-net-bff-with-duende-and-auth0#creating-a-bff-api.
Now I'm trying to understand how to redirect from the frontend to the backend so that a user can authorize using Auth0.

I've used the asp.net core with react project and have only modified the setupProxy.js to add the endpoints that should be forwarded to the backend:

```
    const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');const { env } = require('process');
    
    const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT} :env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:48637';
    
    const context = [
    "/bff/login",
    "/api",
    "/signin-oidc",
    "/signout-callback-oidc"
    ];
    
    const onError = (err, req, resp, target) => {console.error(${err.message});}
    
    module.exports = function (app) {const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {target: target,// Handle errors to prevent the proxy middleware from crashing when// the ASP NET Core webserver is unavailableonError: onError,secure: false,// Uncomment this line to add support for proxying websockets//ws: true,headers: {Connection: 'Keep-Alive'}});
    
    app.use(appProxy);};
```

This still gives me a callback URL mismatch.
the redirect uri should be https://localhost:8443/signin-oidc, but is redirect_uri: https://44466/signin-oidc.

My login component is pretty straightforward right now:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import LoginLogo from './Login_logo';
    import './Login_page.css';
    
    const Login_page = () => {
    
        return (
            <div className="login-page">
                <div className='login-page-header'>
                    <LoginLogo />
                    <h1 className="title">sipster</h1>
                </div>
                <div className='login-page-input'>
                    <button className='login-button'> <a href="/bff/login">Login</a></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default Login_page;
```

Answer (score 0):

It just worked as expected,when you send request with url (port 44466):

```
"/bff/login",
"/api",
"/signin-oidc",
"/signout-callback-oidc"
```

the development server will recognize that it’s not a static asset, and will proxy your request to `http://localhost:8443/....` as a fallback. the [doucment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development) related

similar with the pic

[image]

And if you redirect  in backend ,it  send 302 statue code with target location back ,and it would send another request  as shown in this pic

[image]

You could Press F12 select NetWork and observe the request you've sent
[image]

Comment: Thank you! So the correct callback uri I should register at my identity supplier should be https://44466/signin-oidc?